# Getting an exception Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await

```
        Here is the Code and where i am sending request to fetching the data and first time it is loading fast and when i am coming back from anuyother page then this page is taking too much time that too when i am using      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() within Task.Run().


    ==============================================================================


                    public  Home()
                    {
                        if (HomeModel.GetInstance().GetHomeDataPopulate())
                        {
                            FireContentPageInitialized();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CallRequest();
                        }
                    }
                    private async void CallRequest()
                    {
                        await Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(3000);
                            SetBannerData();
                            SetBrandsData();
                            SetHotDealsData();
                            SetNewlyAddedData();
                            SetRecentlyViewed();
                            SetRecentlyPurchased();
                        });
                    }

    //Sending Requests to fetching data in subscribed events...
                    private void SetBannerData()
                    {
                        ModelController.OnGetHomeBannerDataSuccess += ModelController_OnGetHomeBannerDataSuccess;
                        ModelController.OnGetHomeBannerDataFailure += ModelController_OnGetHomeBannerDataFailure;
                        ModelController.FetchBannerData();

                    }


    //Fetching Data and binding with UI Itemsource...


                    private void ModelController_OnGetHomeBannerDataSuccess(object sender, CustomEventArgs eventArgs)
                    {
                        stackBanner.ItemsSource = null;
                        stackBanner.ItemsSource = HomeModel.GetInstance().GetHomeBanners();

                    }

    ==============================================================================
```

This is my Code..and i added comment line where i am binding UI. I can't add lots of code here because it's too lengthy so i have added only one method which is binding UI and other methods are also doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update view by another thread. To update view created by main thread from another thread you must do something like this. Example pseudo code (I don't know your methods).

```
            await Task.Run(() => {
            try
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    SetBannerData();
                    SetBrandsData();
                    SetHotDealsData();
                    SetNewlyAddedData();
                    SetRecentlyViewed();
                    SetRecentlyPurchased();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

Comment: #Adlorem Actually i did the same but because of using this procedure my page is loading slowly so is there any other way to use Task.Run() thread or to fast Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() that is can load page fast ??

Comment: When i am using  Task.Run() this thread only for UI then initially  my app is opens flexibly but when i am going on another page and coming back on the same then it is calling Task.Run()  again and then throwing that exception. Please Help me out.

Comment: @Manisha You have to update UI in main thread and you can call the data in other threads. I mean you only need to put codes of updating UI into `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

Comment: @ Jack Hua - MSFT  That's what i am saying that i am doing the same but my content is loading slowly.

Comment: Does the data load fast? Maybe that's the reason why content loads slowly.

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT  I meant that App UI is loading slowly if i use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() within Task.Run() so is there any other way to load UI fast ???

Comment: I mean you load the UI after the data comes back, right? Maybe the process of loading data takes too much time and then you will feel like the UI load very slow. If not the case, I need to see your code about UI  to know if there is any other way to load UI fast.

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT Okh i am attaching my code here..and yes when all data are coming back then it is binding the UI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205412/discussion-between-manisha-and-jack-hua-msft).

Comment: Best idea form me to avoid UI lags is implement proper MVVM model.

Comment: How to handle DENY Camera Permission in xamarin forms and where i should handle it.